# use string variable in place of ip address in url of android?

Tags: java, android, ip

I want to use string variable in place of ip address in url call.
I want to make login with ip address and port number in application. then I want to save this ip address in shared preferences and then in url call i want to use that store ip address in shared preferences

I get the ip address of shared preferences like this.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);


    ip= pref.getString("key_ip", null);           // getting Float

    Log.e("ip: ", "> " + ip);
```

Then i call the url using method like this.

```
public static String off33() {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();

            URI uri = new URI("http://10.1.1.82:80/outlet?3=ON");


            httpGet.setURI(uri);
            httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "kirti123"),
                    HTTP.UTF_8, false));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream));

            String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while (readLine != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(readLine);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
                readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
```

so, I want to use ip string in place of url in method 10.1.1.82 means i want to use like this.

```
            URI uri = new URI("http://ip:80/outlet?3=ON");
```

ip is a string variable and in this variable i get 10.1.1.82

so how i cant use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the Strings

```
URI uri = new URI("http://" + ip + ":80/outlet?3=ON");
```

Comment: Thnx a lot...!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
String base = "http://%1$s:80/outlet?3=ON";
String address = String.format(base,ip);
URI uri = new URI(address);
```